# Possibility of Graying Out/Locking Status Icons for Forms that Particular Participants Are Not Eligible to Fill Out

Tags: redcap, desiredcapabilities

I'm working on a REDCap project where we want to gray out and lock the status icons of forms that participants are not eligible to fill out. For example, if a participant is a male, they would not be filling out a pregnancy form. By default, the status icon for the pregnancy form would be grayed out on the Record Status Dashboard, but one could still click on the icon to fill out the form for the male participant. Would it be possible to lock the form for the male participant such that the record status icon isn't even clickable and the form not accessible? Any input regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

EDIT: As an update to this inquiry, I know that there is a way to lock records and or forms manually, as explained by page 8 of this guide here: https://www.health.state.mn.us/docs/communities/fhv/redcapuserguide.pdf

"Locking records prevents users from changing or deleting data from a form. Only those with permission to unlock the form can make changes to the form/record once it has been locked.

Locking a record should only be done if data entry is complete. If you make changes to the database, such as adding new data fields, the records that are locked will need to be unlocked before data can be entered into those new fields. This includes calculated fields. If a calculated field is added to the form, the calculation will not calculate on the locked forms until they are unlocked. To be able to Lock and Unlock records, a user must have the User Right of “Lock/Unlock Records.

You can lock data entry forms individually or an entire record (all forms/events)at once."

**EDIT (with answer in the question):** This question has been answered with the comment marked as the answer below. To reiterate, we can use the "Form Display Logic" settings in the "Data Collection Instruments" section of REDCap. These settings allow one to add in conditional logic such that forms are kept enabled only when the conditional logic is true. This allows users to "lock" or gray out forms that do not apply to select participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a response to my inquiry, REDCap has a Form Display Logic button in the Designer that allows one to set conditional logic as to when to keep forms enabled. When forms are disabled, they are grayed out and are not clickable on the Record Status Dashboard.